# PDF to text convert using python pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, python-tesseract

I am trying to convert many pdf files into txt. My pdf files are organized in subdirectories within a directory. So I have three layers: directory --> subdirectories --> multiple pdf files in each subdirectory. I am using the following code which is giving me this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`. The code works when I convert files in a single directory but not in multiple subdirectories.

It might be quite simple but I cannot get my head around it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob

pdfs = glob.glob(r"K:\pdf_files")

for pdf_path, dirs, files in pdfs:
    for file in files:
    convert_from_path(os.path.join(pdf_path, file), 500)

        for pageNum,imgBlob in enumerate(pages):
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgBlob,lang='eng')

            with open(f'{pdf_path}.txt', 'a') as the_file:
                the_file.write(text)
```

Comment: You are looking for `os.walk`, not `glob.glob`.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Roberts. Now I get this error ```PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'K:\pdf_files': No error.```

Comment: Thanks @aneroid Still getting the error ```PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '000020051-20140528122047.pdf': No error.``` Now it cannot open the pdf file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just solved the problem in a simpler way by adding `*` to specify all subdirectories in the directory:

```
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob

pdfs = glob.glob(r"K:\pdf_files\*\*.pdf")

for pdf_path in pdfs:
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_path, 500)

    for pageNum,imgBlob in enumerate(pages):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgBlob,lang='eng')

        with open(f'{pdf_path}.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(text)
```

Comment: on mac install poppler and tesseract with "brew install poppler tesseract"

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you need [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), not `glob.glob`. `os.walk` provides you with the directory listing recursively. `pdf_path` is the parent dir it's currently listing, `dirs` is a list of directories/folders and `files` is the list of files in that folder.

Use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to form a full path using the parent folder and the filename.

Also, instead of constantly appending to the txt file, just create it outside the 'page-to-text' loop.

```py
import os

pdfs_dir = r"K:\pdf_files"

for pdf_path, dirs, files in os.walk(pdfs_dir):
    for file in files:
        if not file.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            # skip non-pdf's
            continue
        
        file_path = os.path.join(pdf_path, file)
        pages = convert_from_path(file_path, 500)
        
        # change the file extension from .pdf to .txt, assumes
        # just one occurrence of .pdf in the name, as the extension
        with open(f'{file_path.replace(".pdf", ".txt")}', 'w') as the_file:  # write mode, coz one time
            for pageNum, imgBlob in enumerate(pages):
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgBlob,lang='eng')
                the_file.write(text)
```

Comment: Thanks @aneroid. But I neither get any error nor any conversion of pdf files. But as I mentioned, the code works on a single directory at a time.

Comment: One thing it might have to do with specifying files that end with ```.pdf``` but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Added a check to skip non-PDFs

Comment: And [from the docs](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image#how-does-it-work) you may need to add an output folder/path.

Comment: You mean to save the converted files? Can I specify the existing folder path as the output path?

Comment: Sorry, the files are still not being converted.

Comment: _"the files are still not being converted"_ doesn't contain useful information. Are you getting an error? Is it silently failing? Add some `print`s in between to see how far it's progressing in each case. (Add this info in your question.) Also, add the "single folder" version of your code which you say definitely was working.

Comment: Hi, aneroid, it does not give any error but I am not seeing any file being converted either. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: This code was working ```import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob

pdfs = glob.glob(r"K:\converted\*.pdf")

for pdf_path in pdfs:
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_path, 500)

    for pageNum,imgBlob in enumerate(pages):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgBlob,lang='eng')

        with open(f'{pdf_path}.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(text)```. However, since I already have an alternative solution, it should be fine for now. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: `pdfs = glob.glob(r"K:\converted\*.pdf")` will return a list of files ending with `.pdf`, which you're iterating over using `for pdf_path in pdfs`. The code above does the same, with a change to the txt filename (edited above). Alternatively, you could just change your glob expression to be `r"K:\converted\*\*.pdf"` - which is probably the better & easier way.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this currently ```r"K:\converted\*\*.pdf"``` as I also suggested in the following answer. It is easier. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

# Path to the folder containing PDF files
input_folder = "d:/doc/doc"

# Path to the folder where text files will be saved
output_folder = "d:/doc/doc"

# Path to the Tesseract OCR executable (change if necessary)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Get a list of all PDF files in the input folder
files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.endswith(".pdf")]

# Loop through each PDF file and convert it to text using OCR
for file in files:
    pdf_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file)
    txt_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".txt")

    # Convert PDF pages to images
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)

    # Perform OCR on images and extract text
    text = ""
    for image in images:
        # text += pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
        text += pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='ron') # your document language

    # Save the extracted text to a text file
    with open(txt_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
        txt_file.write(text)

print("Conversion complete!")
```